# Meta_query Wordpress. Сортировка по двум произвольным полям, одно из которых может быть не задано. Как сделать?

Tags: php, wordpress

Как реализовать проверку в параметрах meta_query?

У товара есть два произвольных поля:

1 - "Цена" -> 'meta_key' => 'price'

2 - "Цена по акции" -> 'meta_key' => 'special_price'

У каких-то товаров заполнена только "цена", у каких-то и "цена" и "цена по акции".
Соответственно не получается корректно отсортировать (выбрать из базы) товары, т.к. одно поле может быть не заполненным.

Как реализовать проверку "задано ли поле" в параметрах meta_query следующего типа:

По умолчанию сортировать по 'meta_key' => 'special_price', но если у товара special_price не задана, то для них (и только для них) сортировать по 'meta_key' => 'price'.

Пробую так, но не работает:

```
  $args = array(
   'post_type' => 'custom_products', ,
   'relation' => 'OR',
   'meta_query' => array(
     array(
       'key' => 'price'
     ),
     array(
       'key' => 'special_price'
     ),
  ),
   'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
   'type' => 'NUMERIC',
   'order' => 'DESC',
);
```

Comment: @Alex78191 А можно чуть подробнее? Я в курсе, что можно создать несколько query, но в том и дело, что нужен один, в данном случае - это выборка товаров с сортировкой по убыванию цены.
Суть проблемы:
1) Сортирую по полю 'special_price', но 'special_price' есть не у каждого товара, поэтому товары, у которых это поле не задано не будут сортироваться.
2) Сортирую по полю 'price', тут проблема в том, что 'special_price' является приоритетной ценой, если спец.цена задана - она важнее, т.е. это цена со скидкой. Если 'special_price' задана, то 'price' не актуальна.
Поэтому нужна проверка условием.

Comment: @Alex78191 Повторюсь, нужна одна выборка, один query, но он должен учитывать два поля,  'price' и 'special_price', при этом  'special_price' у товара может быть не задан. Отсюда вопрос, как создать такой meta_query, который будет сортировать по полю  'special_price', но если это поле не задано, то сортировку проводить по полю  'price'.

Comment: @Alex78191 Каким образом? Я ведь поэтому и спрашиваю, т.к. не знаю как это сделать ДО запроса на вывод записей. $args - это параметры выборки для WP_Query( $args ), т.е. на момент создания параметров выборки еще негде смотреть задано ли поле 'special_price', это будет ясно уже после работы цикла WP с этими самыми указанными параметрами.

Comment: Посмотри это https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/126772/query-to-sort-a-list-by-meta-key-first-if-it-exists-and-show-remaining-posts

Answer (score 0):

Нужно через два запроса делать или условие ставить, а так максимум можно выжать сортировку сначало по акции, потом по обычной цене. Имхо легче через `get_post_meta()` проверять. 
В основном нужен первый запрос, который отсортирует акцийное, второй обычное. Параметри по логике если есть special_price сортируй, если price и нет special_price или пусто или 0 то сортируй второй список.
Запрос ниже сначало проверяет есть ли акция и не пуста ли она, потом есть ли цена и не поста ли она, выполняется одно из условий то будет выводить пост и сортировать. Тоесть, например есть три товара, один с спец.ценой 99, два другие обычные цены 98 и 100, товары выведет в следуещем порядке 98 99 100.

```
 $args = array(
               'post_type' => 'custom_products',
               'type' => 'DECIMAL(10,3)',
               'meta_query' => array(
                 'relation' => 'OR',
                 array(
                 'relation' => 'AND',
                    array(
                        'key' => 'special_price',
                        'compare' => 'EXISTS',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'key' => 'special_price',
                        'value' => '',
                        'compare' => '!='
                    ),
                 ),
                 array(
                 'relation' => 'AND',
                    array(
                        'key' => 'price',
                        'compare' => 'EXISTS',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'key' => 'price',
                        'value' => '',
                        'compare' => '!='
                    ),
                 )
              ),
               'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
               'order' => 'ASC',
            );
```